# gcc segmentation fault - how can I find a line where it happened?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, segmentation-fault

I'm using Ubuntu and gcc. My application crashes I only have `Segmentation fault` message in console. (previously `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` was reported but now it changed to just `Segmentation fault`).

There are no hints where the problem is so I do not understand how should I fix the problem. I need some hints to find what caused this - ideally complete stack trace or at least object type/method or something like this.

What would be the correct way of troubleshooting such type of problem? (may be compile with some extra flags, run some tools, collect core dump and analyze it somehow?)

Comment: Compile with `-g` and use gdb.

Comment: No idea what the problem is? Using a debugger?

Comment: valgrind & -g3 helped and showed stack trace. by some reason this suggestion was removed by author so I have no answer to accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might well need to enable core dumps with

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

Once you have a core dump, you can look at the program state with GDB:

```
gdb my_prog core
```

You should then have the same view that you would have had if you'd run the program under GDB until it crashed - you could just do that, rather than collecting the core dump. In particular, it will show you which line caused the segfault, and the state of the call stack at that point.

To get the best debugging view, you should tell the compiler to include debugging symbols (`-g`) and disable optimisation (`-O0`).

Comment: i receive `core: No such file or directory` error. i'm not sure how can I force linux to create `core` file

Comment: @javapowered So `ulimit -c unlimited` doesn't force linux to create core file? If so, you should mention this in your question.

Answer (score -2):

you can use the gdb tools to help debuging. 
run gdb ./your_app_name on terminal if you have the gdb installed and you will see some infomation as follow:

```
.....
```

Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./gsvod_client...done.
(gdb)

then input "r" to start your app, if it crashed again, you can type 'bt' to see the line where the problem occured.

Comment: without building with -g and -O0, there's not really any point in this